# How to define domainname in a docker run command?

Tags: email, docker

I want to create a mail server container with docker. I tried with docker-compose.yml file and this has a parameter named "**domainname**" . But without **docker-compose**, using docker run ... I don't know which is the domainname parameter.

Docker-compose.yml:

```
  mail:
  image: tvial/docker-mailserver
  hostname: mail
  domainname: deploymentbox.com
  ports:
  - "25:25"
  - "143:143"
  - "587:587"
  - "993:993"
  volumes:
  - ./spamassassin:/tmp/spamassassin/
  - ./postfix:/tmp/postfix/
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found one answer at this question [Docker issues](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13378). Join hostname and domainname in **--hostname** parameter. For exampe:

```
docker run -d  --hostname mail.deploymentbox.com \
 -p 25:25   -p 143:143   -p 587:587   -p 993:993 \
 -v $PWD/spamassassin:/tmp/spamassassin/   \
 -v $PWD/postfix:/tmp/postfix/ tvial/docker-mailserver
```

I try in my server and run.

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer seem to be the case starting from Docker 1.11+ - using dots in the hostname will not populate the "domainname" property anymore.